# Model binding in angular template driven forms doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to bind the model in angular template driven forms. I created a model class and using it to populate the input field.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2 col-12" [class.text- danger]="nameCode.invalid &&  nameCode.touched">
<label for="inputName"  class="form-control-label"> Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" [class.is-form-invalid]="nameCode.invalid &&  nameCode.touched" id="inputName" name="lotCode"[(ngModel)]="formModel.name" #nameCode="ngModel" aria-describedby="nameHelp" autocomplete="new-password" required>
<small id="nameHelp" class="text-danger" *ngIf="nameCode.invalid && nameCode.touched">Required</small>
```

Component:

```
export class AppComponent  {
formModel: FormModel= new FormModel();
}
export class FormModel {
name: "abc"
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yue9fe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: ... and what is your question? Are you asking us to debug your code, because it does something other than you expect? If so, what *does* it do, and what do you expect instead?

Comment: I would like to bind my input model with the formModel property and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name: "abc"` should be `name= "abc"` (or `name: string = "abc"`). Right now you're declaring type of name as "abc", which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have bind the name as "abc" dataType. So if you want to bind your model with html you can define your formModel class like,

```
export class FormModel {
   constructor(public name="abc"){}
}
```